# Microsoft Word Automation - Embedding Word in MFC - Error saving the document

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, ms-word, automation, ole

I am trying to embed microsoft word inside an MFC SDI SDK application. And I could able to do this using the below link :

[How to embed and automate a Word document with MFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/238611/how-to-embed-and-automate-a-word-document-with-mfc)

But when trying to save the document, it is throwing an error message. Below is the code for saving the document.

```
LPDISPATCH lpDisp;
lpDisp = m_pItem->GetIDispatch();

_Document doc;

doc.AttachDispatch(lpDisp);

doc.Save();
```

Here I am trying to save the document which is already opened using the below function:

```
CString strPath = "D:\\Test.doc";
m_pItem->CreateFromFile(strPath, m_clsid);
```

Following is the error message when calling the function doc.Save():

> The save method or property is not available because this document is
>   being edited in another program

Comment: And it's not open in any other process?

Comment: It is not opened any where other than the MFC SDI application

Comment: I usually don't distrust a computer. How did you verify, that the document isn't opened by any other process?